# Add additional information for substrate user account

Tags: account, address

At the time of creating the user and keys, I need a way to add a field or fields related to this particular blockchain network, such as role.
Is there a solution?

Comment: Please provide more context. How are you creating these users? In a pallet? What are you trying to do that needs roles?

Comment: @Bruno In fact, I want to have a role for each role of user so that I can limit a pellet methods to this roles.

Comment: Have you read about the origin system?

Answer (score 1):

So if you're building a pallet, you could have it update the frame system `data` field in the `AccountInfo`:

```rust
/// Information of an account.
#[derive(Clone, Eq, PartialEq, Default, RuntimeDebug, Encode, Decode, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
pub struct AccountInfo<Nonce, AccountData> {
    /// The number of transactions this account has sent.
    pub nonce: Nonce,
    /// The number of other modules that currently depend on this account's existence. The account
    /// cannot be reaped until this is zero.
    pub consumers: RefCount,
    /// The number of other modules that allow this account to exist. The account may not be reaped
    /// until this and `sufficients` are both zero.
    pub providers: RefCount,
    /// The number of modules that allow this account to exist for their own purposes only. The
    /// account may not be reaped until this and `providers` are both zero.
    pub sufficients: RefCount,
    /// The additional data that belongs to this account. Used to store the balance(s) in a lot of
    /// chains.
    pub data: AccountData,
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/a46183c706e300b1993f28278a273153010d2b0c/substrate/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L751-L768

An example of a pallet that does this is pallet balances:

```rust
type AccountStore: StoredMap<Self::AccountId, AccountData<Self::Balance>>;
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/a46183c706e300b1993f28278a273153010d2b0c/substrate/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L295

That is why when you look up an account on PolkadotJs Apps you will see the account balance information there as well.

If you're looking to add roles take a look at this post:

- [Add roles to accounts](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10281/add-roles-to-accounts)