# Add roles to accounts

Tags: account

Is it possible to add different role to the accounts? I mean some accounts can do more things on the chain than other. How it is possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you describe what you're trying to build it may help for me to give you a more concise answer.

Generally speaking, if you're building a pallet you could have a [`StorageMap`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageMap.html) in that pallet that holds `role` -> `account`. Just keep in mind that storage and storage iteration is expensive on blockchains and it is preferred that you abstract the role to a layer higher than the blockchain (if you can).

Another common pattern in Substrate is to define an `Origin` in your pallet config that have designated permissions e.g. `AdminOrigin` and when you configure your pallet in the runtime, you set the `AdminOrigin`. Example [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/a46183c706e300b1993f28278a273153010d2b0c/substrate/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L447).

You can also [create custom origins](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1390/29) and do [origin checks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eg5uUeUdyI&t=1738s).

Nice video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJ9yuOqwy4s) covering custom origins on [Pallet Collective](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/a46183c706e300b1993f28278a273153010d2b0c/substrate/frame/collective/src/lib.rs#L137-L148).

Depending on what you're trying to achieve a [`SignedExtension`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/sp_runtime/traits/trait.SignedExtension.html) may be the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. Burno has mentioned one.

You can even do this without defining an origin.

For example, the pallet-staking: after calling `bond()`, you become a staker. If you call `validate()` afterwards, you become a validator. And if you call `nominate()` after that, you become a nominator.

Furthermore, you can check the pallet-identity's code. Once you become a identity registration merchant, you have the ability to authorize other accounts.

Basically, all you need to do is define a storage for storing those special accounts. Once a user makes a certain call, you can check if they are in the storage. If yes, then perform the desired action; if no, return an error indicating insufficient privileges.